# Field 'id' expected a number but got '127.0.0.1'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am working on get the number of the video views by ip firstly I creat a views to get the ip of the users and store in this model

```
class UsersByIP(models.Model):
ip_user = models.TextField()

my video model
class Video(models.Model):
        author = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        video = models.FileField(upload_to=get_video_filepath, validators=[validate_file_extension, validate_file_size])
        viewers_by_ip = models.ManyToManyField(UsersByIP, default=None, blank=True)
```

Then this is my view that get the current user ip and if it's not store of the video views then store it

```
         num_views_by_ip = Video.objects.annotate(
                num_views_ip=Count('viewers_by_ip'),
            ).order_by('-viewers_by_ip')
            data = get_object_or_404(num_views_by_ip, pk=pk)
            if not request.user.is_authenticated:
                __, created = Video.viewers_by_ip.through.objects.get_or_create(
                    video=data,
                    usersbyip=self.request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
                )
                if created:
                    data.num_views_ip += 1
```

Comment: It looks like your `pk` is an IP address, not an int value...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem So I should change the `ip_user = models.TextField()` to `ip_user = models.GenericIPAddressField()`

Comment: The error occures in this line `usersbyip=self.request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')`

Comment: You can easily debug. Just look to variables at the problem line.

Comment: This is the variables `into field. Choices are: id, usersbyip, usersbyip_id, video, video_id`